# How to fix a kernel error in Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, boot, linux-kernel

I rent a server HP ProLiant DL120 G6 from Leaseweb.

```
root@lw4:~# uname -r
3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64
root@lw4:~# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
root@lw4:~#
```

When checking the log with journalctl, I found two kernel errors:

```
root@lw4:~$ journalctl -p err
мар 23 17:29:40 lw4.domain kernel: ERST: Can not request iomem region <0x bf7ff000-0x bf800000> for ERST.
мар 23 17:29:40 lw4.domain kernel: i8042: No controller found
root@lw4:~$
```

Tell me about what these errors? How to fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short and simple Google search for the above error shows you that it is a BIOS bug and it's harmless. You can disable it by adding `quiet erst_disable` to the default Grub cmdline.