# Can't install any Linux based OS

Tags: linux, linux-mint, software-installation, system-installation, hardware-compatibility

I tried to clean install linux mint, zorin os and elementary into my windows laptop.

But every time I try to Install any linux OS I get the following error
`ERST:Can not request [mem 0x6feff000-0x6fefffff] for ERST` and the screen starts blinking.

I even tried to dual boot along side windows but it is the same.Although I am able to install any windows os without any problem.

Comment: At least provide the laptop brand/model you are using, as well as BIOS version so people that want to help can have a starting point. Also, the fact that you have tried three Linux distributions doesn't mean that you cannot install _any_ Linux-based OS.

Comment: Apologies @schaiba.I am using a **Dell 10z  1120** with a BIOS version **A06**.

Comment: Usually the error you're mentioning should be harmless and it's BIOS-related. Are you sure that the OS doesn't continue the boot process if you wait for a while?

Comment: Please also specify what method you are using to install? The standard approach is still to use a CD or DVD. For Debian, at least, the most common method is probably to use a small "netinst" CD, get a basic system running, and then download the rest over the network. Other methods are used, of course, but are much less common. Also, what Linux distributions did you try to install?

Comment: @schaida The OS does continue  the boot up but it takes 5-10 minutes every time I boot my laptop.Sometimes it gets stuck on the error screen blinking and doesn't go any further.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I burn the iso using rufus in my pendrive and install using that. For Zorin OS I use "Etcher" app to burn the is in pendrive. I have used similar method to successfully install Ubuntu in my other laptop.

Comment: @MaazShaikh Add that information to the question, please, not in comments. What is rufus? Which distributions have you tried to install?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Rufus is a tool that helps format and create bootable USB flash drives. I have tried to install Mint,Elementary and Zorin. Although sometimes the OS does get install but everytime I boot up it shows the same error screen and rarely does start up the OS.

Comment: I'd recommend trying more standard distributions like Debian/Ubuntu and Fedora. Also, doing a search with the error message brings up https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353360/how-to-fix-a-kernel-error-in-centos-7

Comment: @FaheemMitha thanks Faheem..I am downloading Ubuntu now. How can I access the default grub command line?

Comment: I am not sure about other distros. But for Debian, the install images work for CD/DVD and USB storage. You just need to raw copy them to the device. The web site for rufus suggests that it manipulate the data to create a bootable image (**this is not needed**, and may brake it). In Gnu/Linux use `dd` for Microsoft see https://superuser.com/questions/221559/copy-disc-image-to-usb-device-under-windows Unfortunatly I can not find any good links (as usual “what is easy with Unix, is possible with MS-Windows”)

Comment: @MaazShaikh I don't know what you mean by "How can I access the default grub command line?" Just go through the Ubuntu installation. It's quite simple, I think, and should take care of everything for you. Are you dual booting with Windows? It's not clear.

Answer (score 2):

If your just want a Linux distribution for learning shell scripting, I would wholeheartedly recommend installing Linux in a virtual machine.

Use something like, for example, VirtualBox.

This way, you will have the ability to seamlessly switch between your Linux shell and your more familiar Window environment and you would be able to test out different partitioning schemes, filesystems, network configurations etc. without the fear of destroying your files in Windows. It would also mean less hassle from possibly unsupported hardware.

Later, when you feel more confident, you could install Linux (or some other Unix) on the machine, either as a dual-boot solution or as the only OS on the computer (and run *Windows* inside VirtualBox on the Linux system).

But, as I said, if you just want to learn shell scripting in Linux, install a some virtual machine software, create the empty virtual machine with a 20 GB or so large disk image, and boot the installation ISO.

---

I'm running OpenBSD 6.1 without X11 in VirtualBox on top of a Windows 10 laptop.  This is my main everyday working platform since a couple of years.